# Phpml\Exception\MatrixException Message: Matrix is singular

Tags: php, codeigniter, machine-learning, regression, php-ml

I'm making a program that will predict the next year's collection from
the database using php-ml.

and I'm getting this error.

**Phpml\Exception\MatrixException  Message: Matrix is singular**

Im using this functions

use Phpml\Regression\LeastSquares;

use \Phpml\Math\Matrix;

use \Phpml\Math\Set;

newbie here.

**Regression_controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model("regression_model") ;
    $array = $this->regression_model->display_data();
    $targets = $this->regression_model->display_data2();

    $matrix = new Matrix($array);
    $set = new Set($targets);

    $arraytrix = $matrix->toArray(); 
    $arrayset = $set->toArray();

    $col[] = array_column($arraytrix, 'year');
    $col2[] = array_column($arrayset, 'total');

    var_dump($col);
    var_dump($col2);

    $regression = new LeastSquares();
    $regression->train($col, $col2);

    $predicted = $regression->predict([2018]);

    var_dump($predicted);

    $this->load->view('regression');

}
```

**Regression_model**

```
function display_data()
{
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT year from total_year");
    return $query1->result_array();

}
function display_data2()
{
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT total from total_year");
    return $query1->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises when all the values of a dataset attribute are similar in all records.

```
$samples = [ [1000,3,145], [1000,5,135], [1000,4,143], [1000,3,123]];

$targets = [ 4, 1, 3, 2];

$regression->train($samples, $targets);
```

In the above sample, the first values of all records ar equal to `1000`. Therefore, when `$regression->train($samples, $targets)` is executed it sees attribute count of `$sample` is `2` instead of `3`, which creates a mismatch between array dimension which is `3 x 4` not `2 x 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem but I was able to solve it. Make sure that you don't have the following:

- less than two data
- wrong format

**Less Than Two Data.** Upon trial and error, I've found out that it needs at least 2 data.

**Wrong Format.** Make sure to follow the proper formatting of the target and sample (see the [documentation](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/regression/least-squares/)).

```
$samples = [[60], [61], [62], [63], [65]];
$targets = [3.1, 3.6, 3.8, 4, 4.1];

$regression = new LeastSquares();
$regression->train($samples, $targets);
```

As you can see in `$samples`, it's an array of arrays. So, make sure that each value in your array is an array itself.